# Which programming pattern is an elegant solution for handling a MailChimp mailing list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, design-patterns, model, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I implemented some list managment methods to keep the user-data of my Rails app synchronized with the subscriber data of the according MailChimp list.

(EDIT) Under the hood I am already using the [mailchimp gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mailchimp). I am simply abstracting one level higher **to represent one specific list**.

For now all the logic is in a controller, but I'd rather have a more generic und thus reusable approach (maybe even convert it into a gem someday).

So my first thought is to represent the list as a table-less model, offering the necessary methods to handle it.

```
class MailChimpList
    def add_subscriber
        # ...
    end
    # ...
end
```

**... but I am curious which other approaches exist and which would reflect the idea even better?**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the gem gibbon https://github.com/amro/gibbon to interact with mailchimp. You can fetch lists, campaigns, emails subscribed to lists etc.

Comment: I am already using https://rubygems.org/gems/mailchimp for the implementation. What I am doing, is abstract one level higher and handle **one specific list** only that is related to the according app.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general approach to handling API interactions (not just MailChimp), [Temboo](https://temboo.com) offers a [Ruby SDK](https://temboo.com/download) that normalizes access to 100s of APIs. For example, adding a MailChimp subscriber looks like this:

```
listSubscribe = MailChimp::ListSubscribe.new(temboo_session)

listSubscribeInputs = listSubscribeChoreo.new_input_set()

listSubscribeInputs.set_credential("myMailchimpAccount")

listSubscribeInputs.set_ListId("myMailingList")
listSubscribeInputs.set_EmailAddress("foo@example.com")

listSubscribeResults = listSubscribe.execute(listSubscribeInputs)
```

Check it out if you think you'll be re-using MailChimp for other projects, or trying to integrate other APIs in a similar fashion.

You can find MailChimp methods & docs, customizable code snippets, and live examples here: https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/MailChimp/

(Full disclosure: I work for Temboo. :)